# Create order programmatically in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm using these two methods to create orders programmatically in Magento.

The first one creates a Quote:

```
 public function prepareCustomerOrder($customerId, array $shoppingCart, array  $shippingAddress, array $billingAddress, 
        $shippingMethod, $couponCode = null) 
    {
        $customerObj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
        $storeId = $customerObj->getStoreId();
        $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->assignCustomer($customerObj);
        $storeObj = $quoteObj->getStore()->load($storeId);
        $quoteObj->setStore($storeObj);

        // add products to quote
        foreach($shoppingCart as $part) {
            $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $productObj = $productModel->setStore($storeId)->setStoreId($storeId)->load($part['PartId']);

            $productObj->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true);

            try{
                $quoteItem = $quoteObj->addProduct($productObj);
                $quoteItem->setPrice(20);
                $quoteItem->setQty(3);
                $quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);                                    
                $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);

            } catch (exception $e) {
            return false;
            }

            $productObj->unsSkipCheckRequiredOption();
            $quoteItem->checkData();
        }

        // addresses
        $quoteShippingAddress = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address();
        $quoteShippingAddress->setData($shippingAddress);
        $quoteBillingAddress = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address();
        $quoteBillingAddress->setData($billingAddress);
        $quoteObj->setShippingAddress($quoteShippingAddress);
        $quoteObj->setBillingAddress($quoteBillingAddress);

        // coupon code
        if(!empty($couponCode)) $quoteObj->setCouponCode($couponCode); 


        // shipping method an collect
        $quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
        $quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
        $quoteObj->collectTotals(); // calls $address->collectTotals();
        $quoteObj->setIsActive(0);
        $quoteObj->save();

        return $quoteObj->getId();

    }
```

And the second one uses that Quote to create Order:

```
 public function createOrder($quoteId, $paymentMethod, $paymentData) 
    {
        $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId); // Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
        $items = $quoteObj->getAllItems();                  

        $quoteObj->reserveOrderId();

          // set payment method 
        $quotePaymentObj = $quoteObj->getPayment(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment
        $quotePaymentObj->setMethod($paymentMethod);
        $quoteObj->setPayment($quotePaymentObj);

        // convert quote to order
        $convertQuoteObj = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote');
        $orderObj = $convertQuoteObj->addressToOrder($quoteObj->getShippingAddress());
        $orderPaymentObj = $convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quotePaymentObj);

        // convert quote addresses
        $orderObj->setBillingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getBillingAddress()));
        $orderObj->setShippingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getShippingAddress()));

        // set payment options
        $orderObj->setPayment($convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quoteObj->getPayment()));
        if ($paymentData) {
        $orderObj->getPayment()->setCcNumber($paymentData->ccNumber);
        $orderObj->getPayment()->setCcType($paymentData->ccType);
        $orderObj->getPayment()->setCcExpMonth($paymentData->ccExpMonth);
        $orderObj->getPayment()->setCcExpYear($paymentData->ccExpYear);
        $orderObj->getPayment()->setCcLast4(substr($paymentData->ccNumber,-4));
        }
        // convert quote items
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            // @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
            $orderItem = $convertQuoteObj->itemToOrderItem($item);

            $options = array();
        if ($productOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct())) {

            $options = $productOptions;
        }
        if ($addOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
            $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($addOptions->getValue());
        }
        if ($options) {
            $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
        }
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                $orderItem->setParentItem($orderObj->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId()));
            }
            $orderObj->addItem($orderItem);
        }

        $orderObj->setCanShipPartiallyItem(false);

        try {
            $orderObj->place();
        } catch (Exception $e){     
            Mage::log($e->getMessage());
            Mage::log($e->getTraceAsString());
        }

        $orderObj->save(); 
        //$orderObj->sendNewOrderEmail(); 
        return $orderObj->getId();

    }
```

The process works fine, no errors, and the order is created. But the total is 0 and there are no products in it no matter what I put.

I've traced it and I can confirm that the rows are added to the `sales_flat_quote` and `sales_flat_quote_item` tables, so that is ok. But when running the `createOrder` and calling

```
     $items = $quoteObj->getAllItems();
```

an empty array is always returned, and I have no idea why. I have configurable and simple products in my shop. This happens when I add simple, when I add configurable the error appears as the method

```
    $quoteItem = $quoteObj->addProduct($productObj);
```

returns null.

Comment: i have a similar problem did you find a solution

Comment: What customer ID would you use for a guest checkout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to me, you didn't load product collection, therefore, the cart always return empty. Try this link, it will give you more clear help. [Create order programmatically](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/)

```
// this is get only one product, you can refactor the code
$this->_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'Some value here...')
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->getFirstItem();

// load product data
$this->_product->load($this->_product->getId());
```

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me,

```
public function createorder(array $orderdata)
 {
   $quoteId = $orderdata['quoteId'];
   $paymentMethod = $orderdata['paymentMethod'];
   $paymentData = $orderdata['paymentData'];       
   $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId); 
   $items = $quoteObj->getAllItems();        
   $quoteObj->reserveOrderId();

    $quotePaymentObj = $quoteObj->getPayment(); 
    $quotePaymentObj->setMethod($paymentMethod);
    $quoteObj->setPayment($quotePaymentObj); 

    $convertQuoteObj = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote');
    $orderObj = $convertQuoteObj->addressToOrder($quoteObj->getShippingAddress());
    $orderPaymentObj = $convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quotePaymentObj);

    $orderObj->setBillingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getBillingAddress()));
    $orderObj->setShippingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getShippingAddress()));
    $orderObj->setPayment($convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quoteObj->getPayment()));

    foreach ($items as $item) 
    {
        $orderItem = $convertQuoteObj->itemToOrderItem($item);        
        $options = array();
       if ($productOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct())) 
       {
         $options = $productOptions;
       }
       if ($addOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) 
       {
        $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($addOptions->getValue());
       }
       if ($options) 
       {
          $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
       }
       if ($item->getParentItem())
       {
            $orderItem->setParentItem($orderObj->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId()));
       }
       $orderObj->addItem($orderItem);
    }
     $quoteObj->collectTotals();
     $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);
     $service->submitAll();
     $orderObj->setCanShipPartiallyItem(false);         
    try 
    {

         $last_order_increment_id = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getIncrementId();
         return $last_order_increment_id;            
    } 
    catch (Exception $e)
    {     
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        Mage::log($e->getTraceAsString());
        return "Exception:".$e;
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and delved into the API to find a solution.  I changed the way that I loaded a product by using :

```
$productEntityId = '123456';   
$store_code = 'my_store_code';

$product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($productEntityId,Mage::app()->getStore($store_code)->getId());
```

I found this tutorial to be very useful too :

> http://www.classyllama.com/content/unravelling-magentos-collecttotals

If you are looking for a script on order creation this is a very good start :

> http://pastebin.com/8cft4d8v

Hope that this helps someone ;)