# Magento: Create order programmatically for the items on cart

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to create order manually for the cart items and the payment would be completed manually on the spot and the customers would also be created programatically. Kind of like a pos.

I searched a  lot and found these

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/

http://pastebin.com/8cft4d8v

[Create order programmatically in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877767/create-order-programmatically-in-magento)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/294640/

But none work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function createorder(array $orderdata)
{
   $quoteId = $orderdata['quoteId'];
   $paymentMethod = $orderdata['paymentMethod'];
   $paymentData = $orderdata['paymentData'];       
   $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId); 
   $items = $quoteObj->getAllItems();        
   $quoteObj->reserveOrderId();       
   $quotePaymentObj = $quoteObj->getPayment(); 
   $quotePaymentObj->setMethod($paymentMethod);
   $quoteObj->setPayment($quotePaymentObj);        
   $convertQuoteObj = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote');
   $orderObj = $convertQuoteObj->addressToOrder($quoteObj->getShippingAddress());
   $orderPaymentObj = $convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quotePaymentObj);       
   $orderObj->setBillingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getBillingAddress()));
   $orderObj->setShippingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getShippingAddress()));
   $orderObj->setPayment($convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quoteObj->getPayment()));  

   foreach ($items as $item) 
    {
       $orderItem = $convertQuoteObj->itemToOrderItem($item);        
       $options = array();
       if ($productOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct())) 
       {
         $options = $productOptions;
       }
       if ($addOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) 
       {
        $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($addOptions->getValue());
       }
       if ($options) 
       {
          $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
       }
       if ($item->getParentItem())
       {
            $orderItem->setParentItem($orderObj->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId()));
       }
       $orderObj->addItem($orderItem);
    }

     $quoteObj->collectTotals();
     $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);
     $service->submitAll();
     $orderObj->setCanShipPartiallyItem(false); 

     try 
     {
         $last_order_increment_id = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getIncrementId();
         return $last_order_increment_id;

     } 
     catch (Exception $e)
     {     
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        Mage::log($e->getTraceAsString());
        return "Exception:".$e;
     }
```

}